# Flutter - adding authorization header in HTTP POST request triggers Unhandled Exception: Failed to parse header value

Tags: flutter, dart, http, header, authorization

In Flutter, I am trying to do a HTTP request using POST with authorization. The request sends correctly as long as I don't add the authorization header in the headers.

I am using http dart package

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

And here is the code I am using to send the request:

```
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    String token = await auth.currentUser!.getIdToken();

    var url = Uri.https(
        'us-central1-[my_gcp_project].cloudfunctions.net', 'myfunction');

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
    };

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: body,
      headers: headers,
      encoding: const Utf8Codec(),
    );
```

The body is a <String, List>, such as:

```
var body = '{"mylist":[{"name":"name1","number":"+12345559789"},{"name":"name2","number":"+13456789999"}]}';
```

All attempts fail with the same exception:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Failed to parse header value
#0      IOClient.send
package:http/src/io_client.dart:90
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed
package:http/src/base_client.dart:93
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _withClient
package:http/http.dart:164
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _MhClassState.myfunction
```

I am using the following dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  firebase_core: any
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.1.0
  flutter_contacts: ^1.1.5
  after_layout: ^1.2.0
  pretty_json: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  loading_animation_widget: any

dev_dependencies:
  drive: 1.0.0-1.0.nullsafety.1
  flutter_driver:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.5
  test: any
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Is this a bug with the http package ? (Note that if I comment the line HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token", the request goes through but the server rejects the request (Your client does not have permission to get URL)

Thanks in advance !

JB

Comment: Were you able to solve this?